# Management of erectile dysfunction in type I diabetes

Tags: cardiovascular-disease, type-1-diabetes, neuropathy, lipids, erectile-dysfunction

Type I diabetes is in the long term associated with accelerated vascular and autonomic disease.  One of the consequences of both of these is erectile dysfunction.  What diagnostic tests are used to determine which cause is responsible, and is there any evidence that tight control of glucose, blood pressure, lipids can help reverse these changes, or are they irreversible?

Comment: Welcome to Health.SE  Unfortunately, the question as written is considered broad for this site as it would take a lengthy write-up to fully answer it.  You should try and split this question up and just ask about possible diagnostic tests to determine diabetes as a definitive cause and then ask in a separate question about the reversibility.